# how to evaluate this Number("2/4") in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fractions

Hey guys i want to extract/evaluate the answer 2/4 in a string even ehen doing Number ("2/4") it gives me NaN as a result which is fairly reasonable! So my question is how can i evaluate this fraction from a string?

Comment: `eval("2/4")` (oh...)

Comment: Dude!! Seriously extremely thanks for that quick reply!!! So, can i use this to change the result obtained from regexp? I guss i can..

Comment: @Tushar  this does not work. It parses only the first part of the string. `parseFloat("5/4")` returns 5.

Comment: @Mrityunjay Bhardwaj: Is it always a fraction?

Answer (score 3):

You can do `eval("2/4")`, which will properly result in `0.5`.
However, using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!) is a really bad idea...

If you always have a fraction in format `A/B`, you can split it up and compute:

```js
var s = "11/47";
var ssplit = s.split('/');

document.body.innerText = ssplit[0] / ssplit[1];
```

Note that Division operator `/` will implicitly cast strings "11" and "47" to 11 and 47 Numbers.

Comment: Don't need to cast, `/` will cast it implicitly `ssplit[0] / ssplit[1]`

Comment: @Tushar Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). Note

```
parseFloat("2/4")
2
parseFloat("4/2")
4
eval("4/2")
2
eval("2/4")
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function myFunction() {
       var str = "3/4";
     var res = str.split("/");
    alert(parseFloat(res[0]/res[1]));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `eval` function :

```
eval("2/4");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(str){
    var numbers = str.split("/").map(Number);
    return numbers[0] / numbers[1]; 
})("2/4")
```

Keep in mind this does not check for invalid input.

Comment: Why not `map(Number)`?

Comment: @torazaburo You're right, changed

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the string only valid for numbers like 0-10 and a decimal (.) and all other if included will then result in NaN.

So, what you can do is like this:

```
Number(2/4)//0.5
parseFloat(2/4)//0.5
Number('2')/Number('4');//0.5
parseFloat('2')/parseFloat('4');//0.5
Number('2/4');//NaN as / is not parsable string for number
parseFloat('2/4');//2 as upto valid parsable string
parseFloat('1234/4');//1234
```

So, you can split string then use that like @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev answered for you.